# AngularJS $scope.$watch properties of $scope.foo but send old values to server before change

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have an object $scope.foo in my controller.  I want to watch for any changes in $scope.foo.bar and $scope.foo.baz and do a get request and replace all the data in $scope.foo object.  Before this change happens, I would like to send the data of $scope.foo to the server with the old $scope.foo.bar and $scope.foo.baz.

```
$scope.$watch('foo.bar + form.baz', function() {
    // send old $scope.foo to server with the 
    // previous $scope.foo.bar and $scope.foo.baz
});
```

How would I go about doing this? TIA

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The second parameter of [$scope.$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch) is a function which receives two parameters : the first one is the new value, the second one the old value.

You can simply watch for the whole `foo` object, and set the third parameter of [$scope.$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to `true` in order to compare object for equality rather than for reference. Notice that this can be a pretty bad idea if your object is really large :

```js
$scope.$watch(
    'foo',
    function (newFoo, oldFoo) {
        // send old $scope.foo to server with the 
        // previous $scope.foo.bar and $scope.foo.baz
    },
    true
);
```

You can also watch separately `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` :

```js
var sendAndReplace = function (parameterName, oldParameter) {
    oldFoo = angular.copy($scope.foo);
    oldFoo[parameterName] = oldParameter;

    // send old oldFoo to server with the 
    // previous oldFoo.bar oldFoo.baz
};

$scope.$watch('foo.bar', function (newValue, oldValue)) {
    sendAndReplace('bar', oldValue);
});

$scope.$watch('foo.baz', function (newValue, oldValue)) {
    sendAndReplace('baz', oldValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Does your second example (sendAndReplace()) also preserve old properties on $scope.foo?

Answer (score 2):

The listener function which you provide to the $watch function has two parameters newValue and oldValue as described in the docs here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

In your example you watch on the concatenated string, so to parse the oldValues from the newValues you have to put a seperator between the two variables like so:

```
    $scope.$watch('foo.bar + ";" + foo.baz', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        var oldValues = oldValue.split(";");
        var oldBar = oldValues[0];
        var oldBaz = oldValues[1];
        console.log("oldBar="+oldBar);
        console.log("oldBaz="+oldBaz);
    });
```